# Vanilla JS multi image upload doesn't work when dropping files, does work when selecting files manually

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a script based on [this one](https://codepen.io/ashleystevens/pen/bGepJzm) to allow users to add multiple images to a form.

The form has multiple other inputs and the multi-image selection is part of it.

If I select files 'manually' using the 'click here' then the files are sent with the form submit. If the user drops them onto the 'dropzone' however, they do not get sent with the form. How can I make sure they do?

```js
let dropBox = document.getElementById('dropBox');

['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(evt => {
  dropBox.addEventListener(evt, prevDefault, false);
});

function prevDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(evt => {
  dropBox.addEventListener(evt, hover, false);
});
['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(evt => {
  dropBox.addEventListener(evt, unhover, false);
});

function hover(e) {
  dropBox.classList.add('!bg-lime-100', 'border-lime-300');
}

function unhover(e) {
  dropBox.classList.remove('!bg-lime-100', 'border-lime-300');
}

dropBox.addEventListener('drop', mngDrop, false);

function mngDrop(e) {
  let dataTrans = e.dataTransfer;
  let files = dataTrans.files;
  filesManager(files);
}

function filesManager(files) {
  files = [...files];
  files.forEach(previewFile);
}

function previewFile(file) {
  if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
    return alert('Only JPG, JPEG and PNG files are allowed');
  }

  let fReader = new FileReader();
  let gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

  fReader.readAsDataURL(file);

  fReader.onloadend = function() {
    let wrap = document.createElement('div');
    let img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = fReader.result;
    img.classList.add('rounded-lg');

    let imgCapt = document.createElement('p');

    let fSize = Math.round((file.size / 1024 / 1024) * 10) / 10 + ' MB';

    imgCapt.innerHTML = `<span class="text-md font-bold tracking-tight">${fSize}</span>`;
    gallery.appendChild(wrap).appendChild(img);
    gallery.appendChild(wrap).appendChild(imgCapt);
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="example">
  <input type="text" name="etc">

  <div id="dropBox" class="border-2 border-dashed bg-white border-slate-300 rounded-lg md:p-5 p-10 text-center">
    <p class="mb-2 mt-4">Drag and drop your images here, or</p>
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" id="imgUpload" multiple accept="image/*" onchange="filesManager(this.files)" class="hidden">
    <label for="imgUpload" class="block mt-4 font-bold cursor-pointer"><u>Click here</u> to select from your computer</label>
    <div id="gallery" class="mt-4 grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4"></div>
  </div>

</form>
```

I tried adding this in the previewFile function but that doesn't work:

```js
let dropBox = document.getElementById('dropBox');
let formData = new FormData(dropBox[0]);
formData.append('photos', file);
```

Comment: The source you link to uses `files.forEach(upFile);` in the `filesManager()` function. You don't. `upFile()` appends the file to the form.

Comment: I removed that function because it looked like it uploads the file to a URL, while I want the images to be submitted as part of an existing form. I'm not sure how to make it behave like that with the drag and drop.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I've added something that I think happens in the original codepen file, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="file">` elements are read-only inputs. Files can't be assigned to them. For security reasons user input is necessary to attach a file on the client computer to a form. The "Browse..." or "Choose file..." button provides that user input.

In the case of a drag and drop interaction create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object:

```
const photoFormData = new FormData();
```

...and [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) each file to it using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
files.forEach((file, idx) => {
  photoFormData.append(`photos[${idx}]`, file);
});
```

The index (`idx`) of the file in the `files` array is used to differentiate each file in the FormData object.

When the user submits the form, use a submit [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to post the FormData object holding the files to the location the form is posted to using [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function ({target}) {
  fetch(target.action, {
    method: 'put',
      body: photoFormData
  })
  .then(result => { console.log('Success:', result); })
  .catch(error => { console.error('Error:', error); });
});
```

Appending the files can happen in the `filesManager()` function:

```
function filesManager(files) {
  files = [...files];
  files.forEach((file, idx) => {
    photoFormData.append(`photos[${idx}]`, file);
  }); 
  files.forEach(previewFile);
}
```

---

```
let dropBox = document.getElementById('dropBox');
const photoFormData = new FormData();

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function ({target}) {
        fetch(target.action, {
        method: 'put',
            body: photoFormData
  })
  .then(result => { console.log('Success:', result); })
  .catch(error => { console.error('Error:', error); });
});

['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(evt => {
  dropBox.addEventListener(evt, prevDefault, false);
});

function prevDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(evt => {
  dropBox.addEventListener(evt, hover, false);
});
['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(evt => {
  dropBox.addEventListener(evt, unhover, false);
});

function hover(e) {
  dropBox.classList.add('!bg-lime-100', 'border-lime-300');
}

function unhover(e) {
  dropBox.classList.remove('!bg-lime-100', 'border-lime-300');
}

dropBox.addEventListener('drop', mngDrop, false);

function mngDrop(e) {
  let dataTrans = e.dataTransfer;
  let files = dataTrans.files;
  filesManager(files);
}

function filesManager(files) {
  files = [...files];
  files.forEach((file, idx) => {
    photoFormData.append(`photos[${idx}]`, file);
  }); 
  files.forEach(previewFile);
}

function previewFile(file) {
  if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
    return alert('Only JPG, JPEG and PNG files are allowed');
  }

  let fReader = new FileReader();
  let gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

  fReader.readAsDataURL(file);

  fReader.onloadend = function() {
    let wrap = document.createElement('div');
    let img = document.createElement('img');

    img.src = fReader.result;
    img.classList.add('rounded-lg');

    let imgCapt = document.createElement('p');

    let fSize = Math.round((file.size / 1024 / 1024) * 10) / 10 + ' MB';

    imgCapt.innerHTML = `<span class="text-md font-bold tracking-tight">${fSize}</span>`;
    gallery.appendChild(wrap).appendChild(img);
    gallery.appendChild(wrap).appendChild(imgCapt);
  }
}
```